# React Undefined npm module

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

Im sure this is something simple but for the life of me i can't seem to find an answer to my problem.
Basically Im using react and webpack and I've installed a new package (in this case braintree-web-drop-in), however the package is always appearing as null (undefined) when i import it into my react module and just try to log it out at the top of the module (or anywhere)

package.json:

> "dependencies": {
>       "braintree-web": "^3.32.0",
>       "braintree-web-drop-in": "^1.10.0",

ReactModel.tsx

> import brainTree from 'braintree-web-drop-in'
>   console.log(brainTree);

I can also see that the package seems to have been added to my generated js file through webpack.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like this module doesn't have a `default` export (which the `import` syntax will use if no named export is asked for).

https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in/blob/master/src/index.js#L534

So, in order to see if the module is installed, try this:

```
import { VERSION } from 'braintree-web-drop-in';
console.log('brain tree version: ', VERSION);
```

If that works you can use the `create` with a named import:

```
import { create} from 'braintree-web-drop-in';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that is 100% what was happening there.